# Different roles of a resistor

Tags: resistors, amplifier

I graduated in Physics, then fell in love with electronics, so, in the past few months I have been trying to make heads and tails from it on my own.

Today, as I was reading about amplifiers I got stuck with a resistor in the schematics therein.

Here goes it:

[image: Simple amplifier schematics]

As you can see, it's a simple amplifier, not a big deal, but the resistor R2 is bugging me and I cannot make sense of it!

Now, I don't mean to be rude or boastfull at all friends, but I have already passed the entire Ohm's law and basic functionality of a resistor, both in my physics degree, and now while studying specifically electronics. But here, in this case it does not seem to be a mere case of a voltage being recalculated/modified ( pardon my English ), such as the basic examples of a resistor between to wires, it seems to me that it can have totally different broader roles other than just changing voltage values, am I correct?

If you take a look at it, it seems to be just there, hanging onto the circuit, like a bad suit, one ending just there, hanging, and the other one fixed to ground.

Now, the developed voltage at R2 is supposed to be of such order that it enables a small amount of direct polarization to both transistors. And that's the part I cannot understand, for it's just hanging there, with one end straight to ground!!

How could the voltage that is passing just to one end of the transistor be altered/manipulated in a ways to make the resistor such an important piece in the amplifier?

What did I miss?

Comment: FYI, where you are saying "tension" the usual word in English is *voltage*.

Comment: Not related to your question: Why would someone draw a circuit diagram with +Vcc at the bottom?

Comment: Hey @immibis that schematics was taken from an electronics course I'm currently studying. It's merely presenting the types of amplifiers, it's not for actual usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resistors R1 & R2 form a voltage divider.  This might be more clear if you draw the resistors vertically with R1 above R2.  The top end of R1 comes from the DC power rail, the bottom end of R2 goes to ground.  The midpoint junction of both resistors is the output of the voltage divider.

This provides the quiescent bias for the output transistors.  Note that this is a fairly crappy bias circuit - the value of the bias voltage varies as the supply varies.  But that doesn't detract from its purpose, which is to bias both output transistors right at the point where they are both slightly turned ON.

The bias network makes this a "Class AB" amplifier - both transistors are conducting for very low levels but one or other of the transistors turns OFF as the signal amplitude increases.

The net result of this bias is that crossover distortion is greatly reduced.

Comment: Thanks! Now that you mentioned the first resistor, being 'on top' of R2, I could figure out their role! Wouldn't it be then just a little better if I put a silicon diode in place of R2?

Comment: That's pretty close to what older commercial amplifiers of this sort did.  Couple of things: you need to choose your diode so that it matches the transistors Vbe fairly closely.  Often times, they would use the same transistor as T2 & T3 with B-C connected, with a low-value resistor in series to match the drop (less current in the diode-connected transistor).  And - you would thermally-connect that diode to the output transistors so that the temperature-sensitivity (mostly) cancels out.

Comment: Thanks @Dwayne Reid! I asked about the diode, just to make sure I'm getting the hang of it, as it's not for actual use, it's just a simple schematics I took from a book I'm using to study electronics.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of a voltage divider.

```
VCC --- R1 --- R2 --- GND
```

That sets the DC voltage on the center tap of the transformer, resulting in DC bias on the transistors.